# Is it possible to script FFmpeg to encode multiple files in parallel using a batch script?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch-file

I use a batch script in the shell:sendto folder to do video compression, the script currently looks like this:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
    ffmpeg -i %%a -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%%~na_x265.mp4"
)
pause
```

However, I have noticed that FFmpeg cannot fully utilize all the cores on my machine. I am able to run perhaps 3-4 video compressions in parallel while maintaining the same FPS as compared to running a single video compression

Suppose I want to convert 100 videos, how can I modify this script to run say three FFmpeg instances on the first three videos in parallel, and to start a new instance each time one completes?

Comment: I don’t know how to do Batch file programming in windows, but I believe the best approach would be to use your current `for` loop, but instead of immediately going to the FFmpeg command you build an array/hash based on the value of `%%a` and then loop through those array/hash values and launch the FFmpeg command. As to how to know if/when one ends you can start a new one. Or just use the `-threads 3` option to force it to use three threads per encode like this: `ffmpeg -threads 3 -i %%a -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%%~na_x265.mp4"`. 3x faster encodes without significantly changing your script.

Comment: libx265 does not scale linearly with threads, for example -threads 32 and -threads 64 does not show any speedup. (I have 64 physical cores). It is therefore better to run multiple encodes in parallel, but I am not sure how to write the batch script for this. Eg: when using the run command, its is not clear how to detect when the child console window completes the command.

Comment: Use `start` and give the windows a name, and use `tasklist` to find out when each has finished.

Comment: Had "Windows" not been implied here, it would have been possible to write an answer based on GNU Parallel -> https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `start` your executions in *background process* (`/b`), but there will be a loss of processing / performance with this multiplicity.

See **[start /?](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)** if more the options can suit you better.

```
@echo off & title <nul

setlocal && cd /d "%~dp0"
for %%a in (%*)do call :^) "%%~dpnxa" "%%~dpna_x265.mp4"
    
endlocal && "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & goto %:EOF

%:^)
for /f %%G in ('%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe ^|find/i /c "ffmpeg.exe"
')do if not %%G leq 4 2>&1 "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" 10 & goto %:^)

start "%~nx1" /b /min ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%~2" 
<con: title <nul & title Encoding: "%~nx1" ^| Target: "%~nx2" & exit /b
```

Comment: @aCuria Thank you again! Typo edited!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, It would probably have been quite hard for me to have figured this out myself. I am wondering if theres a way to pipe the "status" of the ongoing background processes back to the foreground window... probably not possible right

Comment: @aCuria I think this is possible take a little help with C#, take a look in my answer in StackOverFlow, if you have some difficulty to apply this, open another question here